# Loop that will look for and delete particular row in Google Sheets script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I want to make loop in google sheets scripts that will in a first place get position of every row where on column B is "N/A" error and then delete the whole row. I start with that code but it doesn't return me the row of "N/A" string.

```
  function DeleteShops() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MainShops");

  for(i=4; i < 282; i++){

  var RowCheck = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValues();

    if (RowCheck ===  "#N/A") {

   var RowToDelete = ss.getRange(i, 2).getRow();
       break;  

    } 

    else {

      continue;

         }

  }

   Logger.log(RowToDelete);

}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleteRow(Integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You have a spare `=`

Just change your line

`if (RowCheck ===  "#N/A") {`

to

`if (RowCheck ==  "#N/A") {`